# home/parent site tab/button/link on sub-site navigation bar link is broken

Tags: 2010, navigation, sub-site, inheritance

Having a little problem and I can't figure out what is wrong.

I have a SharePoint 2010 site `/sites/blah/` that has a few sub-sites: `/sites/blah/one`, `/sites/blah/two`, `/sites/blah/three`. On the parent site I see links to each of the sub-sites in the top navigation bar. On the sub-sites I see a link to the parent site and each of the sub-sites. The problem is the link to the parent site on the sub-sites is broken and points to the wrong place. It points to `/sites/blah/SitePages/Home.aspx` when it should point to `/sites/blah/default.aspx`.

If it matters, I have "SharePoint Server Publishing" activated on the parent site but not the sub-site and I don't want to enable it on the sub-site if at all possible.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would go into Site Settings >> Navigation on each subsite and manually fix the Global Navigation links.

Comment: On that page for "Global Navigation" it has "Display the same navigation items as the parent site" selected. Any way to keep that setting and fix it? It seems that for sub-sites SharePoint automatically tries to add a link to the parent site but it's adding the wrong URL.

Comment: Does the parent site's Global Navigation setting have the default.aspx or the SitePages/Home.aspx listed?

Comment: @ErinL: The parent site's Global Navigation has neither. The tab/button/link to the parent site is only on the sub-sites.

Comment: I'd like to try to replicate this. Which site templates were used for the parent and sub sites?

Comment: @ErinL: I haven't forgotten about this. I just got caught up with an audit and haven't had time to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there just has been a mismatch. You said that you are using the publishing infrastructure and that the top site link should point to `/sites/blah/default.aspx`.

A teamsite without the publishing infrastructure feature activated uses the OOTB library `Site Pages` to store it's aspx sites and the default site is called `Home`.

When enabling the feature above, SharePoint creates a new default library for all pages named just `Pages` with a new "homepage" named `default`.

These libraries must always be referred on any link/URL. So what your top site link is missing is the pages library in the URL.

The correct link should be `/sites/blah/pages/default.aspx`.

As you can see the same navigation on both the parent site and your sub-sites, it means that your subsides inherit the navigation from the parent site.

Navigate to the parent site, go to site settings, under `Look and Feel`, look after `Navigation`.

Scroll down do `Structural Navigation: Editing and Sorting` and mark the link to your parent site. Select Edit and update the URL.

Comment: So what should I do to fix it? How do I fix the mixmatch? Because right now the homepage for the top site is `/sites/blah/default.aspx` but the link SP generates in the top link bar on sub-sites points to `/sites/blah/SitePages/Home.aspx`.

Comment: Updated answer above.

Comment: There is no link to my parent site in the list. The link to the parent site is automatically being added (I think) to the sub-sites.

Comment: Could you share a picture of your navigation from site settings? Either it will be displayed as a folder (still a link) or as a pure link.